# how to access sqlite database across platform

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating a database on my android phone's sd-card at custom location and I am reading this db file byte by byte and sending it to PC through making socket. At PC side I received and write it successfully on disk but when I am opening this file in SQLite database browser then it gives error file is either encrypted or corrupt.

Comment: Check your file transfer code for errors, copying the db file is no problem. Maybe close the db connection so you don't alter the db while transferring